# Clash of clans isn't loading?

Tags: clash-of-clans

This has been giving me problems for some time now. I got on earlier today and it was perfectly fine, but when I got on now, it isn't loading. I've tried readjusting the wifi options and I have reset my iPad and it still doesn't work. I am afraid to uninstall the app because I do not want all of my data to be lost. What can I do?

Comment: Just FYI, no data will be lost if you delete the app, it saves to your AppleID or your Google Play account. It's by the email account you log in with on your device

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't want to lose ANY data

Comment: I'm sure. I just deleted and reinstalled it on my device, it just loaded my village automatically, no loss of data. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the app and then downloading it again from the App Store. No data will be lost, as your village is saved to your Apple ID. Also, I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but when it asks you if you want to keep or remove Game Centre data for the game, tell it to keep - can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks it really did. But the downside is it takes super long to load

Comment: Glad this worked :)